# Как не допустить перезарузки страницы при отправлении формы?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, spring

Пишу корзину интернет магазина

Как не допустить перезарузки страницы при отправлении формы?

Помогите, пожалуйста

```
 <form th:action="'/in-cart'" class="quantity" id="in-cart" method="post">
           <button id="plus-btn" type="button" name="button">
                    <img src="plus.svg" alt=""/>
                </button>
                <input id="cart_quantity" name="quantity" th:value="${session.cart['quantity']}"/>
                <button id="minus-btn" type="button" name="button">
                    <img src="minus.svg" alt=""/>
                </button>
        </form>
```

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                $('in-cart').submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                    var input = $('#cart_quantity');
                    var value = parseInt(input.val());
                    var pr = $('#price');
                    var prv = parseInt(pr.val());
                    var input1 = $('#cart_quantity1');
                    var value1 = parseInt(input1.val());
                    var pr1 = $('#price1');
                    var prv1 = parseInt(pr1.val());
                    var form = document.getElementById("in-cart");
                    $("#total-price").html(value * prv);
                if (value1 > 0) {
                    $("#total-price").html(value * prv + value1 * prv1);
                }
                    $('#plus-btn').click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var $this = $(this);
                        if (value < 5) {
                            value = value + 1;
                        } else {
                            value = 5;
                        }
                        input.val(value);
                        $("#total-price").html(value * prv);

                        if (value1 > 0) {
                            $("#total-price").html(value * prv + value1 * prv1);
                        }
                        form.submit();
                    });
```

Comment: При отправке формы страница все равно перезагрузится. Если такое не нужно - отправляй данные сам. В jQuery есть такие варианты. https://snipp.ru/jquery/ajax-jquery

Comment: @ksa  Спасибо за совет! Подскажите еще, пожалуйста, почему может не работать submit на этих кнопках? 

<button id="plus-btn" type="submit" name="button">
<img src="plus.svg" alt=""/>
</button> <input id="cart_quantity" name="quantity" th:value="${session.cart['quantity']}"/>
<button id="minus-btn" type="submit" name="button">
 <img src="minus.svg" alt=""/>
 </button>

Comment: В твоем примере кнопки `type="button"` - потому дефолтная отправка формы не сработает. А вот с `type="submit"` - как раз и будет срабатывать.

Comment: проблема в том, что я исправил этот недочет и все равно не отправляется(

Comment: Это пока только твои слова. Сделай простой тестовый пример с формой, инпутом и двумя кнопками - ты убедишься что форма будет отправляться, если в ней есть кнопки с `type="submit"`. Пока у тебя нет даже тестового примера. То что ты показал не `html`. И у формы стоит `e.preventDefault()` при `$('in-cart').submit(...)`